# Change process.env.RDS_PASSWORD for aws beanstalk nodejs app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed an aws beanstalk application (with nodejs) which is connected to a RDS database. For some reasons i had to change the master password of this database through RDS Instance options.

Now i would like to update my process.env.RDS_PASSWORD with this new password (for now i have to put it "in clear" in the code).

I didn't find how to do this, neither in AWS Documentation or other locations :/

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can set your environment variables for your EB stack under:

Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment Variables.

You 'should' be able to add/overwrite the RDS_PASSWORD variable here.